# Regular Expression to split (...,...)

Tags: java, regex

I am new in Regular Expression. How can i split Points data from the line below :

> ((X1,Y1),(X2,Y2),(X3,Y3))

Spliting to :

```
(X1,Y1)
(X2,Y2)
(X3,Y3)
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, extracting contents out of brackets or parenthesis may very soon become complex with regex, when nested brackets are introduced. But still in your current case, it seems you can get your results with the use of [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class (Don't try to [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), as it would be slightly more complex):

```
String str = "((X1,Y1),(X2,Y2),(X3,Y3))";

// The below pattern will fail with nested brackets - (X1, (X2, Y2)). 
// But again, that doesn't seem to be the case here.    
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[(][^()]*[)]").matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to the other answer, which looks for `(XXX,YYY)` types of patterns:

```
String s = "((X1,Y1),(X2,Y2),(X3,Y3))";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\(\\w+,\\w+\\))").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```